# How to prove this??

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

Does the following inequality hold?

> $p(n)\leq 2^n,$ where $p(n)$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> prime.

If this is true then it follows that:

If $p(n)=p(m)^x+p(o)^y$, then $\max[x,y] \le n$.

Comment: This follows from Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: @Servaes if i find some idea how to know it's already conjectured..I have found many such things..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you familiar with Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: @BharathGRon The statement you wrote is true, and can be proven very simply using Bertrand's postulate. Not to be insulting, but it is highly likely that any conjectures you come up with, especially if they can be proven as simply as this one, are already proven.

Comment: No im looking at it in wikipedia.

Comment: You may also find Rosser's theorem interesting: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RossersTheorem.html